# OpenQuery Date Selection

Tags: mysql, date, openquery

I have the below openquery which works fine but now I want to select only transactions >= `'2017-07-01'` using `gl_trans.gl_trans_date` but cannot get the correct syntax. The backend database is Informix
I have tried many suggestions via google without success :(

```
SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(PRONTO_L01, 'SELECT 
gl_trans.gl_accountcode,
gl_trans.gl_amount,
gl_trans.gl_trans_date ,
gl_trans.gl_details
FROM gl_trans
WHERE gl_trans.gl_amount <> 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify query on `WHERE` clause & add new column condition with it as shown below. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(PRONTO_L01, "SELECT 
gl_trans.gl_accountcode,
gl_trans.gl_amount,
gl_trans.gl_trans_date ,
gl_trans.gl_details
FROM gl_trans
WHERE gl_trans.gl_amount <> 0 AND gl_trans.gl_trans_date >= '2017-07-01'")
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have said the date >= '2107-07-01'

Comment: and the date returned is in the format 2017-10-03 for the column

Comment: @fgt you're not making a whole lot of sense. Incidentally , a string like '2017-10-23' conveys unambiguous information. A string like '2017-10-03' does not.

Comment: Hi Strawberry.. the date format is YYYY-MM-DD , sorry for the confusion..

Comment: My problem is the openquery as shown does not filter the 10 million records for the date.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Informix date format being MM-DD-2017, resolved using DATE function as below

gl_trans.gl_trans_date >= DATE('07-01-2017)'"

Answer (score 0):

```
     I did something like that and it worked.

    Declare @date DATETIME = '2017-07-01';
    SELECT *
    FROM OpenQuery(PRONTO_L01, 'SELECT 
    gl_trans.gl_accountcode, 
    gl_trans.gl_amount,
    gl_trans.gl_trans_date ,
    gl_trans.gl_details
    FROM gl_trans
    WHERE gl_trans.gl_trans_date  >= ''''' + 
    CONVERT(CHAR(19), @date, 120) + N'''''''))
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, code-only or command-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to people with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks